# Disable PRAGMA recursive_triggers

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

The [android room documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#build()) states that the PRAGMA recursive_triggers is enables by default:

> By default, all RoomDatabases use in memory storage for TEMP tables and enables recursive triggers.

This causes problems for me when I use insert with "onConflict(REPLACE)": If (and only if) recursice_triggers are enables, this fires my onDelete trigger (see [SQLite Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)):

> REPLACE    [...]
>       When the REPLACE conflict resolution strategy deletes rows in order to satisfy a constraint, delete triggers fire if and only if
>   recursive triggers are enabled.[...]

I tried to disable this by adding `db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = 0;");` in RoomDatabase.Callback.onCreate() but this didn't have any effect.

```
    public static synchronized FnsDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDb.class, "mydb.db")
                    .addCallback(triggerCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return  instance;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback triggerCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);

            // adding some triggers here

            db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = 0;");

        }
    };
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it in `RoomDatabase.Callback.onOpen()` instead. It needs to come after the framework's pragma setting. You also don't need the `super` calls in your method overrides.

Comment: Hi Uli, thanks for your reply! The pragma update seems to work now (maybe even before). At least I get a 0 back when I query the pragma recursive_triggers from within the app. Still my onDelete trigger gets fired on REPLACE even though this shouldn't be the case according to the SQLite documentation. Any ideas why that is the case or do you know an elegant work around? Regards

Comment: No idea. Maybe a bug in your SQLite version, or something else causes the trigger to fire?